# Windows Vista Color and Appearance

Tags: windows-vista

Vista Personalization Problems

When I open Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization and click on the "Window Color and Appearance link", I get a small window with "Appearance Settings" on top. There are options to change: Inactive Window, Active Window, Window Text, Message Box. There is a small selection list with themes that I can select.

I don't change much on my laptop. But, I think I remember there used to be a Control Panel window with color options with big buttons to change the color. Did something get messed up on my computer?

Where is this window located?

If something is messed up, how can I fix it?

I am running Vista Basic with an upgrade to Vista Home Premium. I still have all my install CDs.

I posted this to MS Answers. You can see images on my post there:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/vista-personalization-problems/e9847fac-22f7-4add-9a7a-8ed9434cb668?tm=1395872502761

Comment: Don't you only get the Aero visual controls if you have Windows Aero selected as your theme? If you have Vista Basic selected with the traditional windows style without transparency you won't get the translucency and tint options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I understand now.

The window with the big buttons is under the "Customize Color" link on this page/window: "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization".

Themes are different. Themes are in the small window I described above.